# i have warning for Identity is null but i use ? and not fixed this

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

By using this code, I get Claims so I can use it, but it warns me that it is empty

Warning have :

```
Claim? ClaimsIdentity.FindFirst(string type) (+ 1 overload)
```

Retrieves the first claim with the specified claim type.

Returns:

The first matching claim or null if no match is found.

Exceptions:

> ArgumentNullException
> CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference

```
if (HttpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
{
    var IdUser = identity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber).Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindFirst` can return *null*, so you must also use the `?` after it:

```cs
v = identity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber)?.Value;
```

Comment: ... which may still leave `v` being `null`. @Ali